# MS-Access: move to a NavigationControl using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form called frmAanlog with a NavigationControl on it. Using vba I would like to move to one of the forms that you normally reach by clicking on a NavigationButton in the Navigation Control. The form I would like to reach is called frmNavPlant.

I have tried variations of the following line, without success:

`DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmNavPlant", "frmAanlog.frmNavPlant"`

Any suggestions here?
Preferably I would jump to a specific record-ID in frmNavPlant, but already happy with a working jump to the correct form, with the NavigationControl indicating the right page.

Comment: What happens - error message, wrong result, nothing? Is `Aanlog` a misspelling of `Analog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must reference Navigation Form subform container control name, not form name, in Path argument. Access defaults to `NavigationSubform` when Navigation Form is created.

`DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmNavPlant", "frmAanlog.NavigationSubform"`

Comment: Thanks for your swift and perfect replay!